# What about Phusion Passenger would make my CSS render differently than local server development in Rails 3.2?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

The files being served between my local environment, and my deployed environment are the exact same.

However, the layout of the pages is different, and I'm completely stumped. Any experience, or help, would be massively useful.

I'm running Rails 3.2.2. The production setup uses Phusion Passenger. I can replicate the problem setting up Passenger locally, and I can always get it to work when I run the built-in Rails server. My vhost file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName amplifize.local
  DocumentRoot /Users/monvural/Projects/BFBP/amplifize.com/public
  RailsEnv production
  <Directory /Users/monvural/Projects/BFBP/amplifize.com/public>
     Allow from all
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog "logs/amplifize.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was caching turned on in my local environment that messed everything up. Clearing out the /tmp folder under the Rails project fixed everything